# Data classification with javascript

Tags: javascript, classification

I have big data and need to classify those with javascript.

With script:

1. **URLs** will be added to each car model.
2. For the same car model should be the same **URL**
3. when URL will be repeated, this row's current **URL** should move down for next car model

We have the script that solve 1st & 2nd problem. Now we want to solve 3rd item, please help

This is some of data:

```
    <p id="demo0"><span id="ayd0">toyota</span></p>
    <p id="demo1"><span id="ayd1">hyundai</span></p>
    <p id="demo2"><span id="ayd2">nissan</span></p>
    <p id="demo3"><span id="ayd3">honda</span></p>
    <p id="demo4"><span id="ayd4">toyota</span></p>
    <p id="demo5"><span id="ayd5">hyundai</span></p>
    <p id="demo6"><span id="ayd6">lexus</span></p>
    <p id="demo7"><span id="ayd7">porsche</span></p>
```

**it solves 1st**

```
function urlRank (){
    var product, z, dme, aydi3, l=0, m=0;
    var urles = ["link1","link2","link3","link4","link5","link6","link7","link8"];
    for (z=0; z<8; z++){
            aydi3 = "urlaydi"+l;
            dme = "demo"+z;
            product = document.getElementById(dme).innerHTML;
           document.getElementById(dme).innerHTML = product+"&nbsp"+'<span class="'+aydi3+'"'+urles[m]+'</span>';
        l++; 
        m++;
    }
}
```

**it solves 2nd**

```
function clasificat (){
    var product1, product2, aydi1, aydi2, totl, contrl, e=0, f, d=0;
    for (; d<8; d++){
            totl = "demo"+d;
            aydi1 = "ayd"+e;
            e++;
            product1 = document.getElementById(aydi1).innerHTML;
        for (f=0; f<8; f++){
            aydi2 = "ayd"+f;
            product2 = document.getElementById(aydi2).innerHTML;
            contrl = document.getElementById(aydi2).innerHTML;
            if (product1==product2 && contrl.match(/link/) != "link"){
                document.getElementById(aydi2).innerHTML = document.getElementById(totl).innerHTML;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We can't solve third condition, but it very important to us, please give advice, help us.

Comment: It is more dirty way of developing. Parsing html is not a valid way  for sorting and manuplating data. Use javascript object, manuplate it and then render a html template.

Comment: @MehmetOtkun thanks your attention, you mean we should use javascript object insted of `<p id="demo0"><span id="ayd0"></span></p>` or what?

Comment: Yes I said like that. If you post the input and expected output, I can help.

Comment: @MehmetOtkun in original file there are not `<p id="demo0"><span id="ayd0"></span></p>`; but in order to sorting car models especially I give `html & id` for each car model. I trying to understand how to can use javascript object as you say, please help for this

Answer (score 0):

As I understand that you have a list of car model which has id and link,

And you want to order this list group by car model, and each model must have the same link.

If this is OK;

```
  //you can get this data from backend via ajax
  var myCarModel = [
                     {id:0, name:'toyota'},
                     {id:1, name:'hundai'},
                     {id:2, name:'nissan'},
                     {id:3, name:'toyota'}
                     //...
                   ]
  var urles = ["link1","link2","link3","link4","link5","link6","link7","link8"];

  //now you need may models and urls
  //however, how you chose url for model?
  //for example

  var mapedLink = [];
  for(var i=0; i< myCarModel.length; i++){
      var exist = checkExist(myCarModel[i]) //check car model already listed
       var model = checkExist(model);
       if(exist)
          model.link = exist.link;
       else
          model.link = urles[i];
       if(exist)
          mapedLink.splice(exist.index + 1, 0, model); //insert new model after exist model
       else
          mapedLink.push(model); //inser end of the array
  }

  //now you can render your object to html
 var myHtml = '';
 for(var i=0; i< mappedLink.length; i++){
   var model = mappedLink[i];
    myHtml +='<p id="demo'+ model.id +'"><span id="ayd' + model.id +'" class="urlaydi' + model.id + ' ' + model.link + '">'+ model.name +'</span></p>'
 }
 var mycontainer =  document.getElementById("mycontainerid");
 mycontainer.innerHTML = myHtml;
  function checkExist(model){
     if(mappedLink.length){
         var exist = false;
         for(var i=0; i< mappedLink.length; i++){
              if(model.id == mappedLink[i].id){
                  exist = {index:i, url:model.link};
                  return exist;
               }
         }
        return false;
     }
     else
     return false;
  }
```

Please note that; I don't have any idea about your data structure. Just try to give you an opinion.

Please post your sample data structure and show your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

**data structure for car models**

1. *toyota auris*
2. *hyundai elantra*
3. nissan bassara
4. honda jade
5. *toyota auris*
6. *hyundai elantra*
7. lexus gs
8. porcshe cayman

--

n. any car

**data structure for links**

1. link_toyota
2. link_hyundai
3. link_nissan
4. link_honda
5. link_lexus
6. link_porcshe
7. link_bentley
8. link_cadillac

--

n. link_anycar